# unable to fetch from api

Tags: node.js, arrays, api, express

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("server is running");
})

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
})

app.post("/",function(req,res){
    var url = "https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/sessions/public/calendarByPin?";
    var pincode = req.body.pinCode;
    url = url + "pincode=" + pincode;
    var date = req.body.date;
    url = url + "&date=" + date;
    console.log(pincode,date);
    
    request(url,function(err,res1,body){
        res.send(body.centers);
    })
})
```

for the above code (undefined) value is send in `res.send(body.centers)`

body is in json format given as below:

```
{"centers":[{"center_id":596215,"name":"MISSION UHC","address":"MISSION NADIAD","state_name":"Gujarat","district_name":"Kheda","block_name":"Nadiad","pincode":387002,"lat":22,"long":72,"from":"09:00:00","to":"18:00:00","fee_type":"Free"}
```

Comment: To be very exact: is body a JSON string or a JavaScript object?

Comment: My guess is `body` is a string and not an object. Try `body = JSON.parse(body)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to see how body looks

```
request(url,function(err,res1,body) {
  console.log(body);
})
```

If body output in terminal with double quote like :
{
"key": "value"
}
that's mean body is JSON string and you need to parsing it to object with :

```
body = JSON.parse(body)
```

Then send it :

```
res.send(body.centers)
```